# Filtrando uma lista com elementos contidos em outra lista

Tags: android, lista, kotlin

Tenho a classe

```
class estruturaPosicaoXY(val x: Float, val y: Float) {}
```

então preencho uma lista dessa classe

através do método:

```
fun mapearXY(x: Float, y: Float): List<estruturaPosicaoXY> {
        val posicoes = mutableListOf<estruturaPosicaoXY>()

        posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x, y))
        if (x - 1 >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0)
            posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x - 1, y - 1))
        if (x - 2 >= 0 && y - 2 >= 0)
            posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x - 2, y - 2))
        posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x + 1, y + 1))
        posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x + 2, y + 2))
        posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x + 3, y + 3))
        posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x + 4, y + 4))
        posicoes.add(estruturaPosicaoXY(x + 5, y + 5))

        return posicoes
    }
```

Preencho essa lista com o método acima

```
val posicoesMapeadas = mapearXY(100, 100)
```

Preciso usar essa lista pra filtrar uma outra lista

```
val estruturasFilhas =
                    estruturas.filter { it.x == /**/ && it.y ==/**/}
```

Como eu posso usar lista `posicoesMapeadas` pra filtrar a lista `estruturas` pra retornar um objeto onde o `x` e `y` de `estruturas` seja igual ao `x` e `y` de algum item de `posicoesMapeadas`? No linq do c# por exemplo, eu consigo fazer facilmente isso com o método `.Contains`, mas não achei nada parecido no kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que este exemplo soluciona o que você precisa.
Fiz algumas adaptações para torná-lo mais didático. Ou seja, pelo que entendi o resultado é uma lista só com os elementos correspondentes.

Pode rodar no [kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/) para testar e verifique se é isso mesmo. Apenas modifiquei o nome da classe pois parece representar um ponto X,Y

```
data class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int) {}

fun main(){
    
    
    val listaA = ArrayList<Point>()
    listaA.add(Point(100,100))
    listaA.add(Point(200,200))
    listaA.add(Point(300,300))
    
    val listaB = ArrayList<Point>()
    listaB.add(Point(200,200))
    listaB.add(Point(500,500))
    

    val listaResultado = listaB.flatMap { 
        p -> listaA.filter { p.x == it.x && p.y == it.y}
    }
    
    print(listaResultado.toString())
    
}
```